# Vim File Explorer Configuration

Tags: configuration, plugins, vim

I'm setting the below variables in my vimrc to control how windows get split when I bring up the file explorer plugin for vim. But it appears these variables are not being read because they have no effect on how the file explorer window is displayed. I'm new to vim. I know the vimrc file is being read because I can make other setting changes and they get picked up but these don't work. What am I missing?

`let g:explWinSize=10`

`let g:explSplitBelow=1`

`let g:explDetailedHelp=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you got those settings from is outdated. They were valid in vim 6.x, but not 7.x.

For 7.x, use the following settings instead:

```
let g:netrw_winsize=10
let g:netrw_alto=1
```

There is no option for disabling "detailed help" that I can find, but the help provided by netrw in v6 vs v7 is quite different anyway. Read :h netrw for additional info.

Answer (score 0):

Create a gvimrc right beside your vimrc file and add those settings in there.

Comment: And it wouldn't make any sense anyway. gvim reads your .vimrc/_vimrc first.